# System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ssl-certificate

I have been trying to connect to the server using SSLstream.
I have certificate for the connection & all the creds are correct. But somehow it gets the error as below:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. --->   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
at SslTcpClient.Open() in d:\Ishit\Fix\Webservice development - XML communication protocol\Work-by-Developer\ishit\EPP_Webservice\App_Code\SslTcpClient.cs:line 102
at EPP_Transaction_Webservice.Hello() in d:\Ishit\Fix\Webservice development - XML communication protocol\Work-by-Developer\ishit\EPP_Webservice\App_Code\EPP_Transaction_Webservice.cs:line 62
```

Please help me to solve this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: plz post the code aswell, which causing this exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420656/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-an-existing-connection-was-f

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to check if the server you are trying to connect to is black-listing/blocking your IP. This looks like something blocking/rejecting the communication. I had a similar error when my sftp server was blocking the IP I was running the client from.
HTH
Fed

Answer (score 0):

1. Check Connection Encrypted type: SSL3? TLS10? TLS11? TLS12?
   for this may be use firefox > page Info > Security Tab > Technical Details
2. add bellow line app load

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

or

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = default:System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

note: Tls11/Tls12 request .net >= v4.5 ??