# connecting to TFS 2010 using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I tried connecting to TFS using C# . 
   Here is my code :

```
         Uri url = new Uri("http://serverpath/DefaultCollection");

        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("ID", "Password", "Domain");

        TfsTeamProjectCollection coll = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(url, nc);

        coll.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

I get the following error :

```
 The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Inner Exception : {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."}
```

Any solutions about what could be the issue ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to read data from the transport connection : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420656/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-an-existing-connection-was-f)

Comment: Check the server log.

Comment: hmm ! I cant check the server log .. Dont have access to it. Do you know if the server path needs a port number as well ?

Comment: In my code, I've always included the port. Not sure if it's required. Also, typical VS 2010 paths are "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection".

Comment: Thats what the issue was "path" ! It works now . Thanks. Upvoted

Comment: @Michael Add your comment as the answer so we can properly close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the port number, and the `/tfs` in the URI.

Typically TFS 2010 URIs are `http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`.