# HttpClient: Unable to read data from the transport connection

Tags: c#, .net

I am using HttpClient (System.Net.Http) to send a GET request and I occasionally get the following exception:

Unable to read data from the transport connection. The connection was closed before all data could be read. Expected 894 bytes, read 0 bytes.

The instance of HttpClient that I am using is static, [as Microsoft recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.6.1), and I set the Connection header to "keep-alive". I am setting the Authorization header per request and sending the request using the following code:

```
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _authorizationHeader);

        var response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

The exception is thrown on the last line in the snippet. Can someone help me figure out what would be causing this exception to be thrown?

Comment: Try to call to the server with the same query from a browser and check if it answers.

Comment: *Occasionally* is hard to find out. Is the server you are fetching from local? Might it really just sometimes be unavailable like it is the nature of the internet? Any Anti-Virus or Firewall involved?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5420788/2779990

Answer (score 0):

This exception was stemming from the issue described [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7812#issuecomment-305848835).

The fix is to download [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) and set the template to Best Practices (requires reboot) on all relevant servers.