# How do I know what might caused a connection to a ASP.NET WebApi service to be forcibly dropped?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am making a Winforms app that must connect to a ASP.NET WebApi web service that I also made. When I connect to the web service from my computer the Winforms app works, but when I install the Winforms app on some computers it fails to connect to the web service with the following exception:

> System.IO.IOException: Can not write data to the transport connection:
>   The interruption of an existing connection has been forced by the
>   remote host

The problem is that this error might be due to a connection error or due to bugs in either the Winforms app or the web service and I have no idea what might be the cause. I can connect to the server where the web service is hosted. Are there any server logs that I can use to see what might be the cause of this error and if there are, where do I check them?

Comment: have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5420788/6144699)? maybe a firewall is blocking calls?

Comment: Can you make the same requests using the command-line tools `curl` or `wget` (you can get Windows versions)? That would help indicate if it's an issue with your code, Windows' HTTP client stack (proxy settings etc) or the computer's internet connection.

Comment: I can't install curl or wget on customers' computers. What command line program can I use that is installed with Windows instead?

Comment: If you're using PowerShell, Invoke-WebRequest/Invoke-Rest are similar

Comment: You can only capture network packets to see what really breaks the connection. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/netmon/2009/05/13/event-tracing-for-windows-and-network-monitor/ Once the packets are captured, use Network Monitor to analyze.

Comment: It seems that the issue is caused by the server rejecting TLS 1.0. How do I force IIS and the app to accept TLS 1.0 requests from Windows XP users? I need to support Windows XP.