# Error Unable to read data from transport connection. Connection reset by peer. Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I pause my application and then resume after a while, I get this **error** message:

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection. 
>   Connection reset by peer ---> system.net.sockets.....

## I've assigned a class which defines all my objects inside my activity example:

```
public class Connection: Activity
{
    protected SqlConnection con;
    protected string MyIp;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        var prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("Preferences", FileCreationMode.Private);
        MyIp = prefs.GetString("IpAdress", null);

        con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = " + MyIp + "; Initial Catalog = WiOrder; user id = admin; password = 1234;Connection Timeout=5");

    }
}
```

## Here is how I call this class inside activity:

```
public class Main : Connection
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
       //Rest of my code
       con.Open();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (//query,con);
       //.........

    }
}
```

Comment: So `MyIp` is an external and publicly accessible IP address (i.e. *not* localhost) ?and you are trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server database directly from within a mobile app?

Comment: Ip is from a computer with local sql server database; and i'm trying to connect directly from my mobile. Is there any case to delete my sql connection  string after a long pause?

Comment: @daadaa  did you get any solution? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue and I was getting this exception (sometimes) when trying to connect to the server.

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by
> peer.

After many searches, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5420788/4977870)

> **Quote from the answer**
>
> This error usually means that the target machine is running, but the
> service that you're trying to connect to is not available. (Either it
> stopped, crashed, or is busy with another request.)
>
> In English: The connection to the machine (remote host/server/PC that
> the service runs at) was made but since the service was not available
> on that machine, the machine didn't know what to do with the request.

So, you should check your network connection

**For more information,**

Take a look at the similar questions [here](https://forum.devolutions.net/topic28658-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-connection-reset-by-peer.aspx#post110377) and [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103054/httpclient-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-connection-reset-by-peer)

[IOException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ioexception?view=netframework-4.8)