# Error in sending HTTPS get request C#

Tags: c#, api, http, https, get

I have this code to send Http Get Request to https URL but I am getting this error:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Timeout = timeout;//timeout 100 sec by default

            using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
            using (var stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                return response;
            }
```

The URL is working fine from browser and postman.

Comment: which line is giving this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420656/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-an-existing-connection-was-f

Comment: @RakeshBurbure using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())

Comment: try to set `webRequest.KeepAlive=False` and `WebRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10` and `WebRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1`

Comment: add this line just above to create web request and try `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Comment: @RakeshBurbure  that didn't work. Still giving the same error.

Comment: did u add above `SecurityProtocol` line given above comment ?

Comment: What is the timeout value set? please note by default it will be in milliseconds.

Comment: This code is working fine at my end. Please make sure something is not blocking in the service which you are calling.

Comment: I added it ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls . It is accepting TLS only not Tls11 or Tls12

Comment: timeout is 100000 milliseconds

Comment: use above all three `Tls`, `Tls11`, `Tls12` at once

Comment: just copy `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` this and paste in your code as it is

Comment: @ahmed, Is above comment code working fine?

Comment: @ershoaib yes it worked. My problem now is to make it work on .Net Framework 4.0 as TLS1.2 is not supported so instead of that line I am using System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | (SecurityProtocolType)3072; but it is not working

Comment: use this `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =SecurityProtocolType.Tls | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;`

Comment: yes, now it is working. Thanks, @ershoaib RakeshBurbure

Comment: now i add this as answer you then accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add this code just above your `WebRequest.Create(url)`;

If you are using .Net Framework 4.0

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =SecurityProtocolType.Tls | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

If you are using .Net Framework 4.5 and above

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: @ahmed, view the solution might be it help you :)