# ASP.NET MVC Core - Consume API through HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, dotnet-httpclient

I have a Visual Studio solution with two projects; API and MVC. MVC is my MVC-project containing my views etc., API is my API-project containing the API-endpoints and logic. Since I have two projects, I have configured my solution to have multiple startup-projects.

**HttpClient**

```
public const string AuctionAPI = "http://localhost:44337/";
public const string AuctionClient = "http://localhost:44398/";

public static HttpClient GetClient()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(AuctionAPI);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    return client;
}
```

**MVC Controller (Notice: I receive the error on line 6, when I set `HttpResponseMessage` and try to call `client.GetAsync()`**

```
[Route("item/{itemNumber}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexForItem(int itemNumber)
{
    var client = GetClient();
    //ERROR: In next line, HttpResponseMessage it tries to call my API controller and fails
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($@"api/Auction/SeeOneItem/{itemNumber}");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var model = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AuctionItemProxy>();

        return View(model);
    }
    else
    {
        return Content("An error occured.");
    }
}
```

**API Controller (Notice: my breakpoint in this method never hits)**

```
[HttpGet("SeeOneItem/{itemNumber:int}")]
public AuctionItem GetAuctionItem(int itemNumber)
{
    var item = _auctionItemDataFactory.AuctionItems.First(x => x.ItemNumber == itemNumber);
    if (item == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return _auctionItemDataFactory.AuctionItems.First(x => x.ItemNumber == itemNumber);
}
```

**Actual error I receive**

> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection

Comment: Both projects in the same solution using IIS Express? Are you sure the first (API) is actually running when you are running the second (MVC)?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420656/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-an-existing-connection-was-f

Comment: This problem also occurs if circular reference exists inside table definition. Try disabling lazy loading and proxy creation (assumed using EF Core).

Comment: @sellotape Yes, the problem has been correctly identified in the answer. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: @D-johnAnshani Thanks for the link, the problem was identified in the answer below

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thanks for the pointer, the problem was identified in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that the target machine is accessible but the service you are trying to reach is not accessible.

By looking at your code you shared I noticed one thing. If the project is set up to use Https then IIS Express assigns ports starting with 443 resulting in a port like 443xx.
Change your http scheme to https and try again.

```
public const string AuctionAPI = "http://localhost:44337/";
```

to

```
public const string AuctionAPI = "https://localhost:44337/";
```

---

**OR**

Change your project settings to not use SSL

1. Right Click your project Go to properties
2. In properties window go to Debug section
3. Under Web Server Settings un-check "Enable SSL"

---

This issue can also be related to transport level security.