# Xamarin forms iOS App getting crash some times when first time for the day is open

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, crashlytics

I have built an iOS app using Xamarin Forms. it is integrated into firebase crashlatics. so i am getting a error from couple of ios users.

```
Non-fatal Exception: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The socket is not connected.
```

at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException (System.Net.Sockets.SocketError error) <0x105528640 + 0x0001c> in <11ade8ccf21d4e088feeebdfa82d9e3b#d1ce4374a462223982a60b97d03a2ef1>:0
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult (System.Int16 token) <0x1055284b0 + 0x00073> in <11ade8ccf21d4e088feeebdfa82d9e3b#d1ce4374a462223982a60b97d03a2ef1>:0
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1+ValueTaskSourceAsTask+<>c[TResult].<.cctor>b__4_0 (System.Object state) <0x104d714f0 + 0x00173> in <d7378003255d47168c07c9b138461e80#d1ce4374a462223982a60b97d03a2ef1>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.InnerRead (System.Boolean sync, System.Int32 requestedSize, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x10544c170 + 0x0039b> in <11ade8ccf21d4e088feeebdfa82d9e3b#d1ce4374a462223982a60b97d03a2ef1>:0
at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.InnerRead (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x1054467a0 + 0x0024b> in <11ade8ccf21d4e088feeebdfa82d9e3b#d1ce4374a462223982a60b97d03a2ef1>:0
at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x105446120 + 0x00227> in <11ade8ccf21d4e088feeebdfa82d9e3b#d1ce4374a462223982a60b97d03a2ef1>:0
at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.StartOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x105445cd0 + 0x00273> in <11ade8ccf21d4e088feeebdfa82d9e3b#d1ce4374a462223982a60b97d03a2ef1>:0
at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.CheckThrow (System.Boolean authSuccessCheck, System.Boolean shutdownCheck) <0x1054484a0 + 0x0002f> in <11ade8ccf21d4e088feeebdfa82d9e3b#d1ce4374a462223982a60b97d03a2ef1>:0
at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.StartOperation (Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream+OperationType type, Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x1

But still, I have no idea from where and why the problem is happening. anyone having idea

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that the target machine is running, but the service that you're trying to connect to is not available. (Either it stopped, crashed, or is busy with another request.)
So, you may want to check your network or do something like that, you can check this question, it explained the problem well [Unable to read data from the transport connection : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420656/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-an-existing-connection-was-f)