# C# RestSharp.RestRequest call api fail

Tags: c#, .net-core

I first time use RestSharp.RestRequest to call API,

but I always get this error.

this is my code
[image]

the message:

```
2022-10-04 15:30:04.9749 | FATAL | AutoFirewall_NetCoreVersion.Models.ModelAF | response.ErrorException.InnerException = System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 連線已被您主機上的軟體中止。.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10053): 連線已被您主機上的軟體中止。
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.CreateException(SocketError error, Boolean forAsyncThrow)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ReceiveAsync(Socket socket, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveAsync(Memory`1 buffer, SocketFlags socketFlags, Boolean fromNetworkStream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.InitialFillAsync(Boolean async)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.InitialFillAsync(Boolean async)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult(TResult result)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult(TResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecuteFromThreadPool(Thread threadPoolThread)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.InitialFillAsync(Boolean async)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) |  

2022-10-04 15:30:04.9749 | FATAL | AutoFirewall_NetCoreVersion.Models.ModelAF | response.ErrorException.StackTrace =    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at RestSharp.RestClient.ExecuteInternal(RestRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) |
```

but I use python or postman to call API is work.

I have use wireshark to catch packet, it has past api server and my windows server is clear.

I've been thinking about it for two weeks, but I still can't figure out what's wrong....

Comment: Maybe give [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420656/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-an-existing-connection-was-f) a read? it has a lot of info concerning the cited exception from your logs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.